# How do I calculate the exact number of days old in Small Basic

Tags: javascript, python, math, smallbasic

So, for my school assignment, I have to build an ageing program that needs to calculate the number of days old (age in days). It needs to be in the text window, not the graphic window.

I have this:

```
Dayslived = (bob * 12 + (clock.month - month + 12)) * 30.4 + (clock.Day - day)
```

it works but if you enter to give the program a month (as in a number 4 = April) which is before the current month then it does not work.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is your question about python or javascript or smallbasic? Please don't add irrelevant tags to your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need a python example, try this:

   ```
   from datetime import date
   result = date.today() - date(2001, 1, 1)
   print(result.days)
   ```
2. Another way -- using a difference between two Julian Day :

   ```
   def convert_to_julian_day(day, month, year):
       """
       Convert Gregorian calendar date to Julian Day(JD).
       """

       a = (14 - month) / 12
       b = year + 4800 - a
       c = month + 12 * a - 3

       jd = day + (153 * c + 2) / 5 + 365 * b + b / 4 - b / 100 + b / 400 - 32045
       return int(jd)


   jd_today = convert_to_julian_day(22, 4, 2021)
   jd_born_date = convert_to_julian_day(1, 1, 2010)
   age_in_days = jd_today - jd_born_date

   print(age_in_days)  # 4130 days
   ```

For a more detailed Julian Date algorithm, read this: [The Julian Period](https://www.tondering.dk/claus/cal/julperiod.php)